# Unable to target next div in DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, targeting

I am currently having a little trouble using jQuery to locate the next div in the DOM. I suspect it might be due to the `<div>` I am targeting from, being contained within the `<a>` tag.

What I'm aiming for is the `div class="div_name"` to appear during the time the user is hovering over the `div class="island_hover"`

HTML:

```
<div id="interactive_map">
<a href="#"><div class="island_hover" id="1"></div></a>
    <div class="div_name" id="id1"><p>id1</p></div>
<a href="#"><div class="island_hover" id="2"></div></a>
    <div class="div_name" id="id2"><p>id2</p></div>
<a href="#"><div class="island_hover" id="3"></div></a>
    <div class="div_name" id="id3"><p>id3</p></div>
<a href="#"><div class="island_hover" id="4"></div></a>
    <div class="div_name" id="id4"><p>id4</p></div>
<a href="#"><div class="island_hover" id="5"></div></a>
    <div class="div_name" id="id5"><p>id5</p></div>
<div id="interactive_map_close"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.island_hover').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.div_name').fadeToggle(600);
});
```

I have been looking around and have tried the method `.nextAll` but to no avail. I hope somebody will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next()` looks for siblings around the current node's parent node.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

You need to do

```
$('.island_hover').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.div_name').fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: Of course. I do have to clarify, however, that what has happened here is that you have told the jQuery to select the parent <a> around the <div> and then to target the next element in the DOM. Is that correct?

Comment: yes.. but the .div_name will retrieve all the next siblings. You might need some more intelligent way to filter out specific divs

Comment: The end result was 

$(this).parent().next('.div_name').stop().fadeToggle(600);